# How can I make files received by Bluetooth be saved in my own specified folder?

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

By default, any file received through Bluetooth is saved in the downloads folder. How can I create a new folder named `bluetooth` and have received files be saved in it?

Answer (score 0):

When using the standard Gnome BT Manager, you can't change the location. If you are using Blueman (which is better anyways) you can change it by going to the service list and then to the settings of the File transfer module. There you can enter a new path